# A string reference error in services configuration of JWT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

Edit:

So I debugged my code and found that the problems starts because the line

var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY");

In my ServiceExtentions is returning a ***null***, basically the KEY I added from the cmd is not working. Any Idea why?

I am trying to configure JWT to gain a token when I login but I received the error in the image below

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU4Y9.png)

[AuthConfiguration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX6gj.png)

[AuthConfiguration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCA37.png)

[appsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s4tJ.png)

[startup.cs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEl03.png)

[startup 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsGmR.png)

[ServiceExtensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYEok.png)

I added the key in cmd as an admin:

C:\Windows\system32>setx KEY "ffc632ce-0053-4bab-93a4d14aaad" /M

This is the code for my login controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginUserDTO userDTO)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Login Attempt for {userDTO.Email} ");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            if (!await _authManager.ValidateUser(userDTO))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Accepted(new { Token = await _authManager.CreateToken() });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Something Went Wrong in the {nameof(Login)}");
            return Problem($"Something Went Wrong in the {nameof(Login)}", statusCode: 500);
        }
    }
}
```

finally what I added in json

```
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "HotelListingAPI",
    "lifetime": 15
  },
```

Edit 2 :

I solved my problem by adding the key staticly in my appsettings.json file

Comment: The jwtSetting or key variable is not being fetched, it's null I think. What's the value of KEY in your configuration file?

Comment: You should add your configuration file (or at least the part you're fetching data in this snipped of code) to the question

Comment: I will add an Image reference with my configuration file

Comment: Can you debug your code please, check if the key is being returned. Add a breakpoint on the line 31. And check the key variable

Comment: It is returning null acctually at var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY");

Comment: How to i add the Key in the json file?

Comment: Which json file?? You mean the `appsettings.json`?

Comment: yes inside the jwt {}, why is the key not working. I tried adding it multiple times

Comment: Please check my response now, I've edited it and added the key to the jwt section in your appsetting.json

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value from appsettings.json like the below code.

```
var issuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer");
```

`Issuer` should not be a section, you are trying to read it as a section.

**Note**: Please check the appsettings.json do you have this configuration, if not then you have to add it.

Please check the environment also, whether it is reading the correct appsettings..json

Comment: when i did so, an error occurred in ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value,

Comment: so basically you are not able to read the configuration. Have you tried what I have suggested? Issuer is not a section it is key value and you are trying to read as section

Comment: I did do this change var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetValue<string>("jwt:Issuer");

Comment: Can you please show your appsettings.json? How are you running the application?

Comment: but then ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value, errored string does not contain definition for GetSection

Comment: Can you try `var issuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer");` what value is it setting for `issuer`. J is capital in `jwt`

Comment: @NourMawla can you post your full appsettings.json?

Comment: It is present in the appsetting.json image

Comment: @NourMawla post the ServiceExtension.cs . your calling method is static. I want to see how are you passing `Configuration` variable

Comment: @NourMawla try this `var issuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]`, it will work :)

Comment: it gave the same string error, the problem is not the issuer, the problem is that the key value is always null

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fetch your settings using the following code:

```
var jwt = _configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
var lifeTime = jwt.GetSection("lifetime")?.Value;
var issuer = jwt.GetSection("Issuer")?.Value;
```

And check if the `issuer` or `lifetime` variables are null before using it.

And please note that the `lifetime` value is a string

To add your key to the Jwt, do the following:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "HotelListingAPI",
    "lifetime": 15,
    "Key":"KEY"
},
```

And then get it the same way we've got `lifetime` and `issuer`

```
var key = jwt.GetSection("Key")?.Value;
```

Comment: But I just tried it on my machine, the values were returned normally! I don't think the problem is with the issuer or the lifetime. It's with the Key maybe

Comment: I think so too...the key I added through cmd as follows: setx KEY "ffc632ce-0053-4bab-93a4d14aaad" /M